# How can I calculate response rate when I don't know how many people saw the item in the first place?

Tags: inference, algorithms

I have a count of how many people responded to an ad, but I don't have an official count of how many people saw the ad in the first place. I do have an estimate of how many people saw the ad though based on industry knowledge. My question is can I use the estimate to calculate the response percentage? How should I go about this in a way that is statistically sound (i.e. plausible if I was going to present my findings to someone)?

For example, the publisher estimates that 1,000 people saw the ad, and I received 4 responses to the ad. Is a simple 4 / 1000 enough, or should I be doing some other math to figure things like margin of error, etc.? In other words, how would a statistician or data scientist approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is to ask what information you have about the reliability of the publisher's estimates. Without such information you can hardly do better than 4/1000, but in any case you need to keep in mind that this is potentially very unreliable. The "can I use?" question depends on what you want to use this for and how much harm will be done if it is grossly wrong. Sometimes it's better to say "From the given data we can't know X at any reasonable precision" than to use any number as if it were precise.

A sophisticated statistical approach would be a Bayesian analysis, for which you'd need to come up with prior distributions expressing the uncertainty before data for both the response rate and the publisher's estimate. But this is only worthwhile if you indeed have some additional prior information that can be used to improve your knowledge of what is going on (and of course if you have the expertise to run the analysis in that case).

A very rough thing to do is to think hard about the publisher's estimate and to say something like "I believe that the true number of people $n$ who saw the ad is between 200 and 1200" (the publisher may have given you a rather high number, which may be in their own interest); then you can specify at least an interval of plausible rates. (You may also have a look at [Binomial proportion confidence intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) to say something about the precision of $4/n$ given that you know $n$, but this seems less of a problem here than the potential unreliability of the estimate for $n$.)

Keep in mind statistics/data science is not magic; we can try to optimally use the information that is there, but we can't create information out of nothing.